# Electron not show anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm using node.js and electron to build an app.

here is my code
main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const { divine } = require('./controller/currencyExchange');
const searchJsonReady = require('./src/divinePrice.json');

async function createWindow() {
  try {
    const exchange = await divine(searchJsonReady);
    const formatExchange = exchange[0].map(e => parseInt(e) + 'c').join(',');

    let win = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
      }
    });

    win.loadFile('index.html');

    win.webContents.openDevTools();

    win.on('closed', () => {
      win = null;
    });

    win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        win.webContents.send('exchangeData', formatExchange);
      }, 1000);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <div id="exchange-data"></div>

    <style>
      #exchange-data {
        background-color: #eee;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 15px;
        color: black;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

        ipcRenderer.on('exchangeData', (event, data) => {
          const exchangeDataElement = document.getElementById('exchange-data');
          exchangeDataElement.innerText = data;
        });

        ipcRenderer.send('getExchangeData');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the app only shows Hello world, but missing exchangeData. like the img down below

[image]

the formateExchange is one string of data from other API which is "1000c,900c"

im just learn how to use electron, tring to build a small app for practice, but this bug makes me feel so frustrated.

please help thanks!

Comment: if you put `console.log('data', data)`  after `ipcRenderer.on('exchangeData', (event, data) => {` do you get anything?  (does the statement log, is `data` what you expect?)

Comment: Three is an error in the console, you should read it